# javadoc executable not found with maven if even $JAVA_HOME seems correctly set

Tags: java, maven

I am building the [distribution package](https://github.com/wikimedia/wikidata-query-rdf.git) to install wikidata-query-rdf / Blazegraph to be use with my Wikibase installation.

I am struggling to fix a few Java-related issues when I do `sudo ./mvnw package` ([here](https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service) the instructions I am following).

I am running everything under Ubuntu 18.04.

The error I get is

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.1:jar
>   (attach-javadocs) on project common: MavenReportException: Error while
>   generating Javadoc: Unable to find javadoc command: The javadoc
>   executable '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javadoc' doesn't exist or is
>   not a file. Verify the JAVA_HOME environment variable. -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]

Still, if I do `sudo ./mvnw -version`, I get

> Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3;
>   2018-10-24T18:41:47Z) Maven home:
>   /root/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.6.0-bin/7q9b549jss6tgtr7gdokcthm4f/apache-maven-3.6.0
>   Java version: 11.0.4, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 Default locale: en_AU, platform
>   encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-58-generic", arch:
>   "amd64", family: "unix"

I also get 
`which java`

> /usr/bin/java

and

`echo $JAVA_HOME`

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you have a Java 11 JRE package installed rather than a JDK.

On my Ubuntu 18.04 system, there is a `/usr/bin/javadoc` installed.  Running `apt-file find javadoc | bin/javadoc` tells me that it came from the `openjdk-11-jdk-headless` package.  (Not the `openjdk-11-jre-headless` package.)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk` did it for me ( with `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64` as JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here
Resolved with

> cp /usr/bin/javadoc $JAVA_HOME/bin/

Assuming your $JAVA_HOME points to good openjdk location, if not :

> JAVA_HOME=$(update-alternatives --query java | grep Value | cut -d" " -f2 | head -c -10  ) ;

Answer (score -1):

it s not a question of JDK or JRE. Since Java9, this command disappear from bin folder